# Make HTML loader disappear when div is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code below that consist of a `Tab` with DOM elements created dynamically and also a HTML Loader animation. What i'm trying to accomplish is to make my HTML loader disappear when my div `personBorder` is loaded.

Is there any easy way to accomplish this? Because what i'm doing below doesn't seems to be working an i'm not really sure what's the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the code that i tried to do but its not working.

```
var loader = document.getElementById("loader");
var bord = document.getElementById("personBorder");
bord.onload = function () {
  loader.style.display = 'none';   
}
```

```js
var loader = document.getElementById("loader");
var bord = document.getElementById("personBorder");
bord.onload = function () {
  loader.style.display = 'none';   
}

var personArr = [];
var person = {
  ["first-Name"]: "John",
  ["last-Name"]: "Doe",
  ["age"]: 21,
  ["person-desc"]: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin."
};
var person2 = {
  ["first-Name"]: "Paul",
  ["last-Name"]: "Logan",
  ["age"]: 22,
  ["person-desc"]: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. "
};
var person3 = {
  ["first-Name"]: "Sean",
  ["last-Name"]: "Kim",
  ["age"]: 32,
  ["person-desc"]: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin."
};
var person4 = {
  ["first-Name"]: "Ken",
  ["last-Name"]: "Chow",
  ["age"]: 12,
  ["person-desc"]: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin."
};
personArr.push(person, person2, person3, person4);

var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('line1')[0];
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

personArr.forEach((person, i) => {
  var name = document.createElement('h4');
  var desc = document.createElement('p');
  var button = document.createElement('div');
  var border = document.createElement('div');
  name.textContent = `${person['first-Name']} ${person['last-Name']}`;
  desc.textContent = ` ${person['person-desc']}`;
  border.appendChild(name);
  border.appendChild(desc);
    frag.appendChild(border);
    border.className = "personBorder";
    border.id = "personBorder";
});
parent.appendChild(frag);

function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

.line1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.size {
  width: 50%;
}

a.morelink {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

.morecontent span {
  display: none;
}

.lol {
  color: lime;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.loader {
    border: 10px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 10px solid #05788C;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #05788C;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
 animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
.personBorder{
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin:10px; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="size">
        <div class="tab">
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'People')" id="defaultOpen">People</button>
        </div>
        <div id="People" class="tabcontent">
            <div id="loader" class="loader"></div>
            <div class="line1">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: onload event only supports with few tags like listed below.

<body>, <frame>, <iframe>, <img>, <input type="image">, <link>, <script>, <style> Here the reference for onload event

Comment: And why are you asking same question daily. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51258857/make-loader-gone-after-content-is-loaded/51258987#51258987

Comment: Simply call `loader.style.display = 'none';` after `parent.appendChild(frag);`

Comment: @caiovisk That worked really well thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jquery, try this:

```
$("#personBorder").ready(function () {
  $('#loader').remove();
 }
```