# Show CSS preloader overlay till page is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css

Though there are so many related question, none seems to address the issue of using CSS as a preloader as all are image focused.

What i want to achieve is to use the CSS spinner as a preloader and use Javascript to make it disappear after page content is fully loaded, below is the my Code. How do i achieve this with Javascript ?

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
  document.getElementByClassName(".loader").style.visibility = "hidden";
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  background: #111;
}

.loader {
  border: 3px solid #d6336c;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  animation: rotate 2s cubic-bezier(0.26, 1.36, 0.74, -0.29) infinite;
}

#loader2 {
  border: 3px solid #3bc9db;
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  position: relative;
  top: -216px;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  animation: rotate2 2s cubic-bezier(0.26, 1.36, 0.74, -0.29) infinite;
}

#loader3 {
  border: 3px solid #d6336c;
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  position: relative;
  top: -452px;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  animation: rotate 2s cubic-bezier(0.26, 1.36, 0.74, -0.29) infinite;
}

#loader4 {
  border: 3px solid #3bc9db;
  width: 260px;
  height: 260px;
  position: relative;
  top: -708px;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  animation: rotate2 2s cubic-bezier(0.26, 1.36, 0.74, -0.29) infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(-360deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg)
  }
}

@keyframes rotate2 {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg)
  }
}

#text {
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: -857px;
}

.center {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -120px;
  /* margin is -0.5 * dimension */
  margin-top: -85px;
}

​
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta id="viewport-tag" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <title> CSS3 Loading spinner</title>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="center">
    <center>
      <div class="loader" id="loader"></div>
      <div class="loader" id="loader2"></div>
      <div class="loader" id="loader3"></div>
      <div class="loader" id="loader4"></div>
      <span id="text">LOADING...</span></center>
  </div>
  <!--
Display below after loading
-->
  <!-- partial -->
  <h2>
    <font color="white">Hello Everyone Main Webiste Content goes here</font>
  </h2>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How is the approach using an image spinner different from one using CSS. In both cases, you will hide the element that contains the spinner using the same approach? Why does e.g. [Make loader gone after content is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51258857/make-loader-gone-after-content-is-loaded) not solve your problem?

Comment: I have actually tried giving it a shot without success. Blame my low knowledge of Javascript.

Comment: i have edited the post. There are no error codes displayed. I just want a way to hide the main content while page loads and when page is fully loaded, the spinner disappears.

Comment: `There are no error codes displayed.` I added the code to be included in the snipped so that it is unable, and it clearly shows an error message `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByClassName is not a function`.

Answer (score 0):

getElementByClassName - returns a collection of elements, you need to loop the same and set the visibility property

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
if(document.getElementsByClassName("loader")) {
  var k  = document.getElementsByClassName("loader");
  for (let el of  k) {
  el.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  }
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  background: #111;
}

.loader {
  border: 3px solid #d6336c;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  animation: rotate 2s cubic-bezier(0.26, 1.36, 0.74, -0.29) infinite;
}

#loader2 {
  border: 3px solid #3bc9db;
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  position: relative;
  top: -216px;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  animation: rotate2 2s cubic-bezier(0.26, 1.36, 0.74, -0.29) infinite;
}

#loader3 {
  border: 3px solid #d6336c;
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  position: relative;
  top: -452px;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  animation: rotate 2s cubic-bezier(0.26, 1.36, 0.74, -0.29) infinite;
}

#loader4 {
  border: 3px solid #3bc9db;
  width: 260px;
  height: 260px;
  position: relative;
  top: -708px;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  animation: rotate2 2s cubic-bezier(0.26, 1.36, 0.74, -0.29) infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(-360deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg)
  }
}

@keyframes rotate2 {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg)
  }
}

#text {
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: -857px;
}

.center {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -120px;
  /* margin is -0.5 * dimension */
  margin-top: -85px;
}

​
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta id="viewport-tag" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <title> CSS3 Loading spinner</title>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="center">
    <center>
      <div class="loader" id="loader"></div>
      <div class="loader" id="loader2"></div>
      <div class="loader" id="loader3"></div>
      <div class="loader" id="loader4"></div>
      <span id="text"  class="loader">LOADING...</span></center>
  </div>
  <!--
Display below after loading
-->
  <!-- partial -->
  <h2>
    <font color="white">Hello Everyone Main Webiste Content goes here</font>
  </h2>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Loader doesn't show before the content comes up.